# FilteredItemsSelectionDialog in Eclipse E4

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, rcp, e4

`FilteredItemsSelectionDialog` was a handy tool for implementing dialogs that will allow user to select elements from a large set, as it offered a nice filtering feature. But it relies on the `PlatformUI` and `IWorkbench` which are not present in E4. Is there any E4 equivalent of this dialog available out there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is nothing provided. For e4 you can only use the SWT and JFace dialogs, anything else you will have to write yourself.